# Using Facebook SDK In Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebooksdk.net

I am trying to use the Unity Facebook SDK in my game.  Currently, I have added very limited code.  I have only imported the FB SDK asset. When I run the application on my dev computer, the app runs fine.  But, when I push to an Android device and run it, the app crashes on start, with an error stating:

I am not sure if this question is best asked here or in a different channel, but I trying to use the Facebook SDK in my app.  Currently, I am just authenticating with it.  My code works fine on my machine, but when I push to an Android device, the app dies right at startup and the error is:

```
Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path:
```

I don't believe this is an issue with my code, but here is what I had:

```
using Facebook.Unity;

private void Awake()
{
   FB.Init(OnFBInitComplete, OnFBHideUnity);
}
private void OnFBHideUnity(bool isUnityShown)
{

}

private void OnFBInitComplete()
{
        
}
```

I think the issue may be with Google's PlayServicesResolver, but I am not sure how to address it?  I have tried deleting the PlayServicesResolver folder the FB SDK adds to the project and installing the Google com.google.android.appbundle-1.6.0 but that did not help.  Does anyone have any experience resolving this?

I am using:  Unity 2021.2.7f1 and the FB SDK version facebook-unity-sdk-9.2.0
thanks

Comment: Have you tried deleting the current Facebook SDK and import Facebook SDK version 11.0.0 or higher?

Comment: The issue ended up being a conflict with the Google SDK I added as well as the Facebook SDK.  I uninstalled both SDK's and then installed Google first.  Then, when I installed the Facebook SDK, I just didn't import the Google resolver, as that was already added.  That seemed to have fixed the issue.